# application.properties encoding in quarkus

Tags: java, encoding, quarkus

I want to use:

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "some.name")
String someName;
```

in my service, to get some String value for it. This property contains symbols supporting UTF-8, that's why I get "Unsupported characters for the charset 'ISO-8859-1'"

Any ideas, how could I get property without breaking encoding in quarkus?